# Linq Include and Where Clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following linq statement:

```
var result = _context.Settings
                     .Include(x => x.Files)
                     .Where(y => y.Files.Where(f => f.SettingFile == true))
                     .Select(z => z.Deleted == null)
                     .ToList();
```

The thing I want to do is to get all the settings from the table. I also want to include the files-table and get all the files that has the SettingFile true. But I keep get the following error:

> Cannot implicity convert type IEnumerable(UploadedFile) to bool.

Here Is my UploadedFile-model:

```
[Required]
public string FileName { get; set; }
[Required]
public string FileExtension { get; set; }
[Required]
public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }

public Guid? FormAnswerId { get; set; }
public Guid? LicenseHolderId { get; set; }
public Guid? CaseId { get; set; }
public Guid? ErrandId { get; set; }
public bool SettingFile { get; set; }
```

Here is my Setting-model:

```
    public class Setting : ModelBase
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string DisplayTab { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UploadedFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Modelbase:

```
public abstract class ModelBase : EntityBase
{
   public DateTime? Deleted {get; set;}
}
```

What am I doing wrong with my query?

Comment: Where clause return an IEnumerable, try this `.Where(y => y.Files.Any(f => f.SettingFile == true))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish, but I can explain your issue.

A `Where()` clause is a `Func<T, bool>`. You pass in an instance of `T` and it returns a `bool` value.

In this line `.Where(y => y.Files.Where(f => f.SettingFile == true))`, you're returning a `IEnumerable<T>` where it should be returning a `bool`. This is what's causing the error. You can resolve the error by changing the `y.Files.Where(f => f.SettingFile == true)` to `y.Files.Any(f => f.SettingFile)` or `y.Files.All(f => f.SettingFile)`. However, I don't think this is what you're trying to accomplish.

Edit: Since you're trying to get all the Settings that have the `SettingFile == true` then do the following:

```
_context.Settings
        .Include(x => x.Files.Where(f => f.SettingFile == true))
        .Select(z => z.Deleted == null)
        .ToList();
```

Edit: After further communication in the comments, you said you wanted a collection of `Setting`. So you'll just need to remove the `.Select(x => z.Deleted == null)` and you should be golden.

```
_context.Settings
        .Include(x => x.Files.Where(f => f.SettingFile == true))
        .ToList();
```

I don't know your use case, but it might be advisable to add another `Where` condition to exclude any `Settings` that don't have `Files` where the `SettingFile` is `true`.

```
_context.Settings
        .Include(x => x.Files.Where(f => f.SettingFile == true))
        .Where(x => x.Files.Any(f => f.SettingFile == true))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Read my question. I want to get all the settings with the files that has the SettingFile == true.

Comment: The thing Is that I have tried that to. But hat returns List<bool> instead of List<Setting>..

Comment: My Setting-model inherits from a ModelBase-model. Sorry for not have provided that. But when I remove the select-clause with the Deleted == null, it works and returns List<Setting> instead of List<Bool>